# How to get an html content when there are linebreaks using a preg_match?

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-replace

How to include the line-breaks in my regex when doing a `preg_match` of html source?

php

```
preg_match('/Корица:<\/b><\/td><td>(.*)<\/td>/im', $table[0], $korica);
```

html(also this is what is in `$table[0]`):

```
<tr>

            <td><b>Година на издаване:</b></td>

            <td itemprop="datePublished">2009</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td><b>Корица:</b></td>

            <td>Мека</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>

            <td><b>Език:</b></td>

            <td itemprop="inLanguage">Български</td>

          </tr>





                      <tr>

            <td><b>Средна оценка:</b></td>

            <td>                  Продуктът няма оценка                  </td>

          </tr>
```

If i use `preg_match_all` i will get all the html after the Корица. But what i want is to get only this **Meka** from the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(.*)` part in your regular expression to non-greedy `(.*?)`, or even better - `([^<]*)`, which matches everything that is not `<`.

Comment: Thank, this did the magic width a bit work around. I used : `preg_match('/<td><b>Корица:<\/b><\/td>(.*?)<td>(.*?)<\/td>/is', $table[0], $korica);` and i got i needed.

Answer (score 1):

If "Meka" is always alphanumeric, then something like this might work:

```
    preg_match('/Корица:<\/b><\/td><td>([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<\/td>/im', $table[0], $korica);
```

[a-zA-Z0-9]* should match only alphanumeric characters. You might have to consider a space too, in which case you should use [a-zA-Z0-9 ]* (Notice the space before the closing ])

Comment: the problem is that `Meka` is Cyrillic and can't match this regex, i try to use the `[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}]` which i believe should be the correct one but failed again.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `[\p{IsCyrillic}]*` alone

Comment: hm, i received this warning: `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p at offset 56`. tried also